# How to add order by option on get statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, get

Hello i am having some trouble figuring out how to add order by on my get statement. What i want is to add order by so when i print them to have them ordered.

This is what i have tried but no results

```
$kasses = $this->db->from($this->kasses);
$kasses = $this->db->order_by("color", "asc");
$kasses = $query = $this->db->get(); 
return $kasses = $query->result();
```

here is where i get the database

```
$kasses = $this->db->get('kasses')->result_array();
```

and here i print it on screen

```
$kassa=''; 
foreach($kasses as $kass){
    if($kass['stock_alert']>=$kass['stock']){
        ?>
        <a href='#' onclick='showAjaxModal("index.php?modal/popup/kasses_edit/<?=$kass['id'];?>");'>
        <?php echo $kass['type']." / ".$kass['color']." / ".$kass['dimensions']."cm : <span style='color:brown;font-weight:bold'>".$kass['stock']."</span></a><br/>";
        }
```

Any idea how may i achieve that ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try `$kasses = $this->db->get('kasses')->order_by("color", "asc")->result_array();`

Comment: You don't need to save every query instance in `$kasses` just `$kasses = $this->db->get('kasses')->result_array();` is enough remove all other

Comment: @DevsiOdedra thanks for the reply, i tried the code but no results, when i load the page i just shows that it load but doesn't stop

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out 
this is how i did it

```
$this->db->order_by("color_id", "desc");
$kasses =   $this->db->get('kasses')->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$this->db->from('kasses');
$this->db->order_by('color_id','desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result_array();
    //$kasses = $query->result_array();
}else{
    return array();
}
```